# How do I produce a dynamic MySQL pivot table with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

### What I have:

I have a table in MySQL named "updates" that currently holds the following information:

[image]

### What I need:

What I need is the following:

[image]

### What I have done so far:

I have the following MySQL query that works:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
     CONCAT(
       'MAX(IF(Date = ''',
   Date,
   ''', Description, NULL)) AS ',
   CONCAT("'",Date,"'")
 )
   ) INTO @sql
FROM updates;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Action, ', @sql, ' FROM updates GROUP BY Action');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

### The actual Question

I am not able to work out how to execute this using PHP so that I can display this output on a webpage. Is anyone able to either provide me with the PHP code to perform this or point me in the right direction of information required.

I have read a number of articles but I think the issue is that I don't know what I'm actually looking for. At first I assumed it was how to run prepared statements within PHP but this didn't appear to help.

Comment: Are the number of columns always fixed?

Comment: Forget the question how did you generate that table? :D

Comment: Which one? The second table? If so, I just run my last section of code I posted in MySQL. NOTE: This does not work in phpmyadmin, it must be ran from the MySQL command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using mysqli (and not PDO) you can't use a simple query() because you want to execute multiple commands. You will need to use multi_query() in combination with store_result(), more_results() and next_result().

Here is some code I used once:

```
$db=mysqli_connect($databasehost,$databaseuser,$databasepass,$databasename) or die ("Connection failed!");
$result = $db->multi_query($sql);

if ($err=mysqli_error($db)) { echo $err."<br><hr>"; }

if ($result) {
  do {
  if ($res = $db->store_result()) {
      echo "<table width=100% border=0><tr>";

      // printing table headers
      for($i=0; $i<mysqli_num_fields($res); $i++)
      {
          $field = mysqli_fetch_field($res);
          echo "<td bgcolor=lightgray><b>{$field->name}</b></td>";
      }
      echo "</tr>\n";

      // printing table rows
      while($row = $res->fetch_row())
      {
          echo "<tr>";
          foreach($row as $cell) {
            if ($cell === NULL) { $cell = '(null)'; }
            echo "<td>$cell</td>";
          }
          echo "</tr>\n";
      }
      $res->free();
      echo "</table>";

    }
  } while ($db->more_results() && $db->next_result());
}
$db->close();
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need from inspecting the page once created. However, I get the following error message: Warning: mysqli_num_fields() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\ActionPlan\updates.inc.php on line 60

Comment: @Petay87 Hey, strange I didn't catch that before. Yes. $result is a boolean in case of multi_query(). Maybe this is left over from a single-query() example of mine. If you change the `$result` in `$res` in the part `// printing table headers` it should work better (I think). (changed in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

This a bit of code how to access to a database with MySQLI if this could help you

```
<?php
$servername = "hostIP";
$username = "lescours_username";
$password = "password of the data base";
$dbname = "lescoursDB";
 //Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo "La connexion au serveur a etez interompu, Merci d'essayez plus tard";
}else{
    $sql = 'SELECT nom FROM uiotable where nom= \'' . $nom_ut . '\'';
    //$numRows = $result0->num_rows;
    if (!$conn->query($sql)) {
        echo "Nom d'utilisteur incorrecte ";return;
    }else
        {   $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            echo $row["mo_pas"];
        }       
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. You can always run every query from your set as a separate query() call. this is universal rule for running multi-query statements.

```
$mysqli->query('SET @sql = NULL');
$mysqli->query(<<<HERE
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
     CONCAT(
       'MAX(IF(Date = ''',
   Date,
   ''', Description, NULL)) AS ',
   CONCAT("'",Date,"'")
 )
   ) INTO @sql
FROM updates;
HERE
);
$mysqli->query("SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Action, ', @sql, ' FROM updates GROUP BY Action');");
$mysqli->query("PREPARE stmt FROM @sql");

$res = $mysqli->query("EXECUTE stmt");
var_dump($res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

but please remember that by this kind of query your are essentially running an SQL injection against your own database. As long as the field type is `date` it cannot do any harm, but for any text type - watch out!