# Pivot table (associative array) data

Tags: php, arrays, pivot-table

I have data in the following format returned from my database:

```
user_id | video_id | liked
0         341       1
1         765       1
0         534       1
3         981       1
```

I need to pivot this table into the following form:

```
user_id | 341 | 765 | 534 | 981
0         1     0     1     0
1         0     1     0     0
3         0     0     0     1
```

What I'm doing is making a single row per user id and a single column per video id, 0 should be the default value unless the video is liked.

For my initial testing and experimentation I was using python's pandas library like so:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
pivoted_df = df.pivot_table(
    index='user_id',
    columns='video_id',
    values='liked',
    fill_value=0,
)
pivoted_df.to_csv('pivoted_data.csv')
```

This is easy and works perfectly, but now I need to do the same in php and I couldn't find any pandas alternatives. The other solutions I've seen use key names for columns that don't work here since the columns can be any number.

To be clear about the actual data structure in php, the fetched data from the database looks as follows:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 0
            [video_id] => 341
            [liked] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [video_id] => 765
            [liked] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 0
            [video_id] => 534
            [liked] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 3
            [video_id] => 981
            [liked] => 1
        )
)
```

And it needs to look like this:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 0
            [341] => 1
            [765] => 0
            [534] => 1
            [981] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [341] => 0
            [765] => 1
            [534] => 0
            [981] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 3
            [341] => 0
            [765] => 0
            [534] => 0
            [981] => 1
        )
)
```

Comment: Why not change the database query? Why do this in code?

Comment: And what have you tried so far. Your question does not show one line of coding which with you have attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: Is 'liked' always 1 resp. true (because the database query filters for such rows only), or can it be 0 resp. false too?

Comment: @lukas.j `liked` is always 1, I figured having the column would be a bit less confusing than not having it. My database system is mysql and there is no good way to do it there.

Comment: [SQL Query: Rows to Columns Pivot into PHP Array / HTML Output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15028124/2943403) and [Pivot dynamic html table using mysql and php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14492552/2943403) and [pivot html table using php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21345762/2943403) and [How do I produce a dynamic MySQL pivot table with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39961886/2943403) and [How to display Dynamic pivot table using php mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77013320/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$input = [
  [ 'user_id' => 0, 'video_id' => 341, 'liked' => 1 ],
  [ 'user_id' => 1, 'video_id' => 765, 'liked' => 1 ],
  [ 'user_id' => 0, 'video_id' => 534, 'liked' => 1 ],
  [ 'user_id' => 3, 'video_id' => 981, 'liked' => 1 ]
];

$result = [];

$video_ids = array_unique(array_column($input, 'video_id'));
$video_ids_flipped = array_combine($video_ids, array_fill(0, count($video_ids), 0));

foreach ($input as $item) {
  $user_id = $item['user_id'];
  if (!array_key_exists($user_id, $result)) {
    $result[$user_id] = ['user_id' => $user_id] + $video_ids_flipped;
  }
  $result[$user_id][$item['video_id']] = $item['liked'];
}

$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: I needed to change `$result[$user_id][$item['video_id']] = $item['liked'];` to `$result[$user_id][$item['video_id']] = 1;` but that seems todo the trick. tbh I don't quite understand how some of the functions work in combination but its much more performant than @Olivier answer so marking this as accepted

Comment: I'll need to learn more about array manipulation I suppose.

Comment: Please stop answering duplicate questions.  Please do not post code-only answers -- they do not help people to learn the reasons for your design choices.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the desired pivot transformation in PHP, you can create a custom script that processes the data fetched from the database. Here's a PHP script to pivot the data:

```
$data = [
['user_id' => 0, 'video_id' => 341, 'liked' => 1],
['user_id' => 1, 'video_id' => 765, 'liked' => 1],
['user_id' => 0, 'video_id' => 534, 'liked' => 1],
['user_id' => 3, 'video_id' => 981, 'liked' => 1]];
$result = [];
 if (!isset($result[$user_id])) {
    $result[$user_id] = ['user_id' => $user_id];
}`$result[$user_id][$video_id] = $liked;
```

}

```
$result = array_values($result);
print_r($result);
```

This script processes the data fetched from the database and creates the desired pivoted format. It initializes an empty result array, iterates through the database rows, and populates the result array accordingly.

Now, addressing your questions:

Why not change the database query? It's often preferable to perform such transformations in code when the database schema or query is not under your control or when you want to keep the raw data intact for other purposes.

Is 'liked' always 1? Based on your description, it seems that 'liked' is always 1. If it can be 0 or false, you can modify the script to handle those cases by setting the value accordingly in the result array.

What if more than one user_id has the same video_id? This script overwrites the value for a specific user_id and video_id combination. If you want to aggregate likes from multiple users for the same video_id, you can modify the script to add the likes instead of overwriting.

Comment: This code is not valid.